# Upgrading Ubuntu when having drivers from xorg-edgers

Tags: nvidia, xorg

I noticed that xorg-edgers had some warning about Ubuntu distro upgrade. What is the problem exactly?

Do I really need to completely remove my nvidia drivers when I do a distro upgrade?
And would this be the case with the default drivers that Ubuntu it self provides in additional drivers?

I am on 14.04 release and I am just thinking ahead for the upcoming 14.10 upgrade. 
I am using the 340 driver from xorg-edgers.

I used the guide here: http://www.ubuntuupdates.org/ppa/xorg-edgers
To add the PPA.

As you can see there are also some important notices there which talk about the subject I am trying to ask about in here.

Comment: Added more info to the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

General rule: when upgrading manually installed PPA's need to be disabled. The system will do this for you while upgrading. But from topics on AU it seems that this sometimes causes problems.

Mosttimes (but not always) you can re-use a PPA in a new release so I would 1st try to track down those PPA's and see if there are versions for the new release (be it the current one or a PPA that got a new name or version). There is no guarantee that the PPA's you used in 1 release are available in another release. The PPA might have become obsolete (hopefully because of Ubuntu adopting similar features), break your system or just stop working.

> Do I really need to completely remove my nvidia drivers when I do a distro upgrade?

It is adviced to remove drivers you installed that are not included by default. So not just for the video card.

3rd party software is the most likely cause for problems with upgrading.